# PHP bind_param not defined

Tags: php, mysqli, bindparam

I am working in MAMP trying to make a login function.
My connection code is:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$db = "world";

$mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);

if($mysqli->connect_error){
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

My login function:

```
if (isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['p'])){
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['p']; //hashed password

if(login($email, $password, $mysqli) == true){
    header('Location: ../protected_page.php');
    }else{
    echo 'failed login';
    }
}
function login($email, $password, $mysqli){
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT USERID, USERNAME, PASSWORD, SALT FROM USERS WHERE EMAIL = ? LIMIT 1")){
    $stmt = $mysqli->bind_param('s', $email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $username, $db_password, $salt);
    $stmt->fetch();
}
```

Error:

> [17-Oct-2015 08:46:06 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method mysqli::bind_param() in /Users.../Site/include/functions.php on line 24

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `bind_param` for your statement, like this:

```
$stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
```

You have already defined `$stmt` one line before that. `$mysqli` does not have a `bind_param` function.

Comment: That was the issue, thanks a lot

Comment: You are welcome, Jordan.

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

From the manual, you can see, this is not a method of the mysqli object but of the mysqli_stmt object.

You are also destroying the mysqli_stmt object when you run `$stmt = $mysqli->bind_param('s', $email);`